# How to count the occurence of negative and positive values in a column using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
FID IID data1 data2 data3 
1   RQ00001-2   1.670339    -0.792363849    -0.634434791    
2   RQ00002-0   -0.238737767    -1.036163943    -0.423512414
3   RQ00004-9   -0.363886913    -0.98661685 -0.259951265
3   RQ00004-9   -9  -0.98661685 0.259951265
```

I want to count the number of positive numbers in column 3 (data 1) versus negative numbers excluding -9. Therefore, for column 3 it will be 1 positive vs 2 negative. I didn't include -9 as this stands for missing data. For data2, this would be 3 negative versus 1 positive. For the last column it will be 3 negative versus 1 positive.

I preferably would like to use awk, but since I am new I need help. I use the command below but this just counts all the - values but I need it to exclude -9. Is there a more sophisticated way of doing this?

```
awk '$3 ~ /^-/{cnt++} END{print cnt}' filename.txt
```

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result (corresponding to the sample 4 sample input lines)

Comment: _For data2, this would be 3 negative versus 1 positive_ Why? The `data2` column contains only negative values.

Comment: please update the question to address a) if a zero can show up in the 3rd thru Nth columns and b) how to count a zero (positive? ignore?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- determine the number of negative and positive values for the 3rd thru Nth columns

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NR>1  { for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
                 if ($i == -9) continue
            else if ($i <   0) neg[i]++
            else               pos[i]++
        }
      }
END   { printf "Neg/Pos"
        for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)
            printf "%s%s/%s",OFS,neg[i]+0,pos[i]+0
        print ""
      }
' filename.txt
```

This generates:

```
Neg/Pos 2/1 4/0 3/1
```

**NOTE:** OP hasn't provided an example of the expected output; all of the counts are located in the arrays so modifying the output format should be relatively easy once OP has provided a sample output

Comment: If you use `%d` instead of `%s` for numbers then you don't need `+0` - `printf "%s%d/%d",OFS,neg[i],pos[i]`

Comment: you're skipping zeros, by convention they are counted as positive.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
NR == 1 {
  for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++) header[i] = $i
}
NR > 1 {
  for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
    pos[i] += ($i >= 0); neg[i] += (($i != -9) && ($i < 0))
  }
}
END {
  for(i in pos) {
    if (header[i] == "") header[i] = "column " i
    printf("%-10s: %d positive, %d negative\n", header[i], pos[i], neg[i])
  }
}' file
data1     : 1 positive, 2 negative
data2     : 0 positive, 4 negative
data3     : 1 positive, 3 negative
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v c=3 '
NR > 1 && $c != -9 {
   if ($c < 0)
      ++neg
   else
      ++pos
}
END {
   printf "Positive: %d, Negative: %d\n", pos, neg
}' file

Positive: 1, Negative: 2
```

Running it with `c=5`:

```bash
awk -v c=5 'NR > 1 && $c != -9 {if ($c < 0) ++neg; else ++pos} END {printf "Positive: %d, Negative: %d\n", pos, neg}' file

Positive: 1, Negative: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
NR > 1 && $3 != -9 {$3 >= 0 ? ++p : ++n}
END {print "pos: "p+0, "neg: "n+0}'
```

Gives:

```
pos: 1 neg: 2
```

You can change `++n` to `--p` to get a single number `p`, equal to number of positive minus number of negative.

Answer (score 1):

Below you find some examples how you can achieve this:

**Note:** we assume that `-0.0` and `0.0` are positive.

**Count negative numbers in column `n`:**

```
$ awk '(FNR>1){c+=($n<0)}END{print "pos:",(NR-1-c),"neg:"c+0}' file
```

**Count negative numbers in column `n`, but ignore `-9`:**

```
$ awk '(FNR>1){c+=($n<0);d+=($n==-9)}END{print "pos:",(NR-1-c-2*d),"neg:"c-d}' file
```

**Count negative numbers columns m to n:**

```
$ awk '(FNR>1){for(i=m;i<=n;++i) c[i]+=($i<0)}
       END{for(i=m;i<=n;++i) print i,"pos:",(NR-1-c[i]),"neg:"c[i]+0}' file
```

**Count negative numbers in columns m to n, but ignore `-9`:**

```
$ awk '(FNR>1){for(i=m;i<=n;++i) {c+=($i<0);d+=($i==-9)}}
       END{for(i=m;i<=n;++i) print i,"pos:",(NR-1-c[i]-2*d[i]),"neg:"c[i]-d[i]}' file
```